# What is the best way to add a persistent WebSocket listener to android app?

Tags: android

I have a websocket listener in my app that was setup as a background service and started in the Application class.  This allows the app to listen and switch activities as needed.

Of course, with the newer background limitations on Android this is no longer working correctly.  I've tried to upgrade the service to a JobIntentService but it gets interrupted (as intended).  I think I'm thinking about this wrong and have two options -

1. Start a foreground service at app startup and rely on notifications anything that happens when  the app is backgrounded or,
2. Forget the service altogether and simply bind the websocket listener to each activity as it starts up (via a single Activity superclass that all my activities rely on.) or to the app class itself. A JobService will create and destroy my listener anyway.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach?  Is there a clear winner? Is there a different approach I am missing?